# Mask UIWebView as a button to display the 'Show in Calendar' action sheet allowed in app store?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, eventkit

I need to jump to iOS calendar and show a specific day. I read through the documentation and there is no schema url for the calendar app but I could find a hack that is embedding a date into a UIWebView (which I made it look like a button). That makes an action sheet displays the options 'Create Event' and 'Show in Calendar' when touched. It works great, but I'm not sure if that's safe to do in a native app. Any experience submitting code like that to the app store?

Comment: What if there is no internet?

Comment: it's a local content, I'm using loadHTMLString: method to inject it

Comment: Alrighty then. As long as it works fine it shouldn't be a problem. But doing stuff like this does cause unexpected breaking. Just be careful.

Comment: I think it's alright to do this, you're not using any private API here.